# Time frame of Rita Indiana's video "Da Pa' lo' Do'" (Dominican Republic)

Tags: colonization, spain, infantry, caribbean

This question is about the history of the Dominican Republic.  Look at the uniform shown in the beginning of Rita Indiana's [video](https://youtu.be/Y72XAybPTnU) "Da Pa' lo' Do'," which means "There's enough for both," where "both" means D.R. and Haiti.

What historical period does this uniform represent?  Red jacket, blue trim, white pants.  I wonder if this was the Spanish infantry uniform.  During what period(s) was the Spanish infantry active in the western part of the island, or along the border?

But perhaps this is the Haitian army's uniform, and the setting is the Haitian occupation of the eastern part of the island?

What about the second character's uniform?  It's a strange blue -- not a navy blue.  Is this a low-budget or non-historically correct version of the navy I see for that period when I look in google images?  Or is it supposed to represent the ragtag style dress of the Haitian revolutionary forces?  I am very, very confused what sides these two soldiers are supposed to represent, and what the historical period is supposed to be.  I understand the theme of the song and the video but I'm having trouble getting the details.

Bonus question: what was the D.R. called during Spanish rule (1861-1863)?  I would like to know, ideally, what it was called in English and also what it was called in Spanish, if there was a different name in the two languages.

Comment: The musket looks like a muzzle-loader.

Comment: I would suggest comparison against these images: http://miniaturasmilitaresalfonscanovas.blogspot.com/2013/03/los-uniformes-del-virreinato-de-nueva.html

Comment: @T.E.D. - I'm sorry, I don't know the relevance of the muzzle-loader.